# How much performance difference could be assumed from an XAMPP server to a real Server

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I am still a learner and building my FIRST web site linked to a MySQL DB. **I am using XAMPP as my local host platform and using a core i7 laptop of 2.1GHz with 16GB RAM**.

My DB has around 36,000 rows and a query takes around 0.09 seconds. So, my questions are;

1) will this query time be less (less than 0.09 seconds) when I run the queries in a real web hosting server? (if I want it to be like that, what are the things to be considered when chosing a web host?)

2) how much of query time increase could be expected if there are 100 sequential requests from end users? (is it like 0.09 seconds/query * 100 queries = 0.9 seconds?)

Please be kind enough to give me some important points to consider regarding thisscenario. Please note that I am new to DBMS world, so all your advices will help me a lot. Thanks a lot in advance.

- EDIT
  Following the danblack's answer, my query is a simple one with one table. I tried with multiple tables with normalization, but found that sinngle table DB schema is simpler and provide faster queries. But experimenting it to prove it further by altering DB schema and queries. The current query is something like this,

SELECT advertisement.ad_id, advertisement2.heading

```
FROM advertisement

  WHERE advertisement.offered = 1 AND

        advertisement.engine_capacity <=2000 AND

        advertisement.year >=2000 AND advertisement.year <=2016 AND

        advertisement.price <=1000000000 AND

        advertisement.mileage <=100000 AND   

        advertisement.car = 1 AND

        advertisement2.used = 1 AND

        advertisement2.petrol = 1 AND

        advertisement2.automatic = 1

  ORDER BY advertisement.price DESC

  LIMIT 100
```

And I am using ad_id as the PK. And using Indexes on engine_capacity , year , price and so on (on the tabe columns which are used in the query).

- EDIT 2

In the query what changes are the values which are held in each column. For example engine_capacity <=2000 can be changed as engine_capacity <=3000. And similarly other values too. This is an Automobile selling web site, so the buyers can chose their requirements and request the query with chosen values in them.

The SHOW TABLE is as follows;

```
CREATE TABLE `advertisement` (    
 `ad_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,    
 `date_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `offered` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `wanted` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `heading` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `engine_capacity` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `year` year(4) NOT NULL,
 `price` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `mileage` mediumint(6) unsigned NOT NULL, 
 `car` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `van` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `sedan` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `hatchback` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `coupe` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `suv` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `mpv` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `station_wagon` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `convertible` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `bus` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `van_van` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `lorry` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `used` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `reconditioned` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `brandnew` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `petrol` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `diesel` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `hybrid` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `electric` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `phev` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `gas` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `manual` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `automatic` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `tiptronic` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `other_transmissions` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ad_id`,`user_id`),
 KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
 KEY `idxprice` (`price`),
 KEY `idxtime` (`date_created`),
 KEY `idxengine_capacity` (`engine_capacity`),
 KEY `idxyear` (`year`),
 KEY `idxmileage` (`mileage`),     
 KEY `idxcar` (`car`),
 KEY `idxused` (`used`),
 KEY `idxpetrol` (`petrol`),
 KEY `idxautomatic` (`automatic`),
 CONSTRAINT `advertisement2_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=36001 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And the EXPLAIN results the following;

[image]

As I mentioned I tried with the table normalizing by moving columns to dedicated tables, but that increased the query time significantly and this table gives leat times at the moment. Any advice/comment is highly appreciated!

Comment: Add `EXPLAIN SELECT .....` statement output and `SHOW CREATE TABLE advertisement`. Which part of this query frequently change? Read [query optimization](https://github.com/jynus/query-optimization) for what indexes should be there.

Comment: The only way to tell is to test. You can use a test framework such as Apache JMeter to simulate the workload.

Comment: Please have a look at my EDIT 2.  @mustaccio, thanks for the reply, is it possible to run Apache JMeter with XAMPP platform/environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The physical distance between the Server and the Client may be the main criteria.  0.09 seconds is the roundtrip time for a few thousand miles (or km).  A simple way to check this is to do `SELECT 1;` a few times.  For *same* machine, you should get very close to 0.00.  For opposite sides of, say, the US, you might get 0.09s.

As for hardware...

1. The most important performance difference is SSD drives a lot faster than HDD drives.
2. The rest of the hardware metrics don't matter much.

Some details:

- CPUs are only slightly faster than they were 20 years ago; the CPU speed is probably not much difference between your machines.
- MySQL won't use more than one CPU (in a single query), so the number of cores only comes into play when you have unusually high traffic.
- RAID striping can help some.
- Battery Backed Write Cache in a hardware RAID controller helps writes a bunch.
- Network bandwidth may make a difference, but only in huge resultsets -- but those tend to be impractical for many reasons.
- You 36K rows are a tiny fraction of the 16GB RAM.  So you have a lot of growth potential.  Even if your data gets to be bigger than can be cached in RAM (actually `innodb_buffer_pool_size`), the RAM size *may* be an insignificant factor.

Bottom line:

1. Start with whatever is easiest/cheapest.
2. If you get into performance problems, *first* check to see if it can be improved by adding a composite index, rethinking an algorithm, using summary tables, reformulating queries, etc.  Some of these will give you 10x performance/space improvement.  As already implied, hardware changes are not likely to give you more than 2x.

As for the schema:

- A one-column index on a true/false flag is virtually useless.  Toss them.
- van/sedan/coupe/etc sounds like a choice -- Consider using ENUM or some other way to put those into a *single column*.  Since there are about 12 choices, a `1-byte` ENUM works fine.  If you need multiple options, then a 2-byte `SET` (or `SMALLINT UNSIGNED`) would work for multiple-choice.  If you want to discuss this further; tell us what the user can choose.
- `INT(6)`: The `(6)` means nothing; you get a 4-byte integer.
- Let's see the most important `SELECT`; I'll bet a 'composite' index will speed up the query a bunch.

Your specific questions:

When would you have "100 sequential requests" from a single user?  Yes, that would take 9s, and we should try to optimize the query.  Usually, you would have "100 concurrent requests"; *each* one might take only slightly more than 0.9s, and the whole set might finish in 1-2s.

As for the query,

- Have your client leave out things that the user does not care about.  I guess `price` (`price <=1000000000`) was such?
- I would combine true/false flags together into a `SET` or `INT UNSIGNED`, then test for car, used, petrol, and automatic all at once.
- Does anyone ever ask for `offered = 0`?

Based on that `WHERE`, I would have

```
INDEX(offered, price)
INDEX(offered, year)
INDEX(offered, engine_capacity)
```

I put `offered` first because it is handled with `=`; I did not include the other `=` columns pending changes due to my suggestions above.

One range column (price, year, engine) comes last.

`INDEX(offered, price)` won't be used for filtering (since you have a "don't care" value for `price`), but might be used effectively for the `ORDER BY`.

For this type of table and query, the best option for scaling is to minimize the size of the table.

Your table is "small".  However, the query presented is likely to get slower and slower as the table grows.

Your `EXPLAIN` shows a 5-way "Index merge intersect".  Adding an `INDEX` with those 5 columns will run somewhat faster.  The problem is, different variants of the query will need different indexes.  Figure out what most people ask for with "=" (that excludes price, for example) and build an `INDEX` with them.  I would expect `car_type` (a single column, not 12 columns) to be a common one.  So

```
INDEX(offered, car_type, price)
```

Might be the most useful index (after consolidating types).

Change the schema; research what queries are common; then come back for more advice.

Comment: Thank you very very much for the time and effort you put to give a very detailed answer...I am quite new to this DB world, and have NO background in CS and a self learner. So I am going through your comments one by one. This is just for a web site that I am trying to develop to grasp the techniques, and hoping to build a real one based on that. If I explain what it does, this is a car listing web site: where sellers can list their cars and buyers can select them.

Comment: The values you see in the query are actually the pre-assumed query filtering values that a buyer might input (example: price <=1000000000, in here the buyer wants to see all the cars which are less than 1000000000 in price. So the same applies to other entities too. I am experimenting with table normalization and trying to optimize my query performances. I came across one problem though, for the same query and DB schema, I am getting two different results for the EXPLAIN SELECT statements. Is it possible?

Comment: @BuV8 - "just for a web site that I am trying to develop to grasp the techniques" -- Good!  That is an excellent way to sharpen your skills.  Another one of my mantras: "Normalize, but don't over-normalize".  Do some experimenting, you will eventually understand that mantra.  (Meanwhile, I can't give you any quantitative advice -- much of is in a "gray area".)  I once saw the same 'digested' query produce 6 different `EXPLAINs` (out of 40 runs with different values).  It's rare, but possible.

Comment: @BuV8 - I have several blogs that touch on the issues you are encountering.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql ; http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav

Comment: Thank you very muc Rick. I dunno how to appreciate your help. I am in my early 30s, graduated from a different field, but web dev took my heart....so wanna try something...who knows....haha....thanks a lot Rick again. Yes I am going through EXPLAIN and listening to videos on query optimization, and my Normalized DB is now giving considerably good performance. But wanna improve further. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Is your database settings configured the same way on XAMPP to what the "real" server is? Is the version of MySQL different in a way that matters?

Obviously web hosting is a shared service so it might be a touch slower. There is a possibility that the service provider will have faster disk and CPUs too.

On a shared VPS the innodb buffer pool is shared with other users so, as a least recently used cache, your data may get flushed out earlier meaning added disk time on queries.

Question 2, sequential fetches of same query - if its exactly the same query (including values), then all the rows of the table will be off disk and the non-first queries should be slightly quicker. Also requests can occur in parallel and there are multiple CPUs/threads so 100 requests isn't necessary a multiplication of time.

0.09 seconds may not be too bad, but without the query, table structure (`SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}`), or `EXPLAIN {query}` its hard to say if it could be faster.

I wouldn't expect an extremely large blowout of this time from a service provider. Cheap services are cheap due to larger contention and lower effective resources for your service. If XAMPP's mysql database is using (more than just allocated) 10G then using a 1G VPS service won't get the same result.

On a first small website I wouldn't expect any major problem from a hosting/VPS provider.

Comment: Thank you very much danblack. Since I am a learner, I would like to know which settings need to be configured same as XAMPP? If I need to gain a considerable time reduction when I move my web site to a real hosting service, what are the factors to be considered (like CPU speed, bandwidth)? please be kind enough to let me know. thanks again.

Comment: if you are going for a shared hosting database you won't have a choice to make it all the same as what you want. If you have a VPS (dedicate DB to you), then you can configure it how you want. Main point it take a note of differences if you have differences in your query time or query plan (`EXPLAIN {query}`);

Comment: Thanks danblack. Please have a look at my EDIT in the question. So as I understood, if i wanna go with higher query speeds, I would go with a : dedicated DB (better for broader choice in DBM), higher CPU, higher CPU #/ thread. Am I right ? or did I miss anything?

Comment: A dedicated DB in the form of a VPS or Cloud database service will offer you the ability to scale up/tune which a shared provider can't offer. At the moment there's more performance that can be gained by better indexing/query. Might answer later if someone else doesn't.

Comment: thank you very much. Really appreciate your help. Kindly provide some more details if nobody does